# Getting issue while posting XML to tally

Tags: xml, integration, tally

When I request to export data via XML interface from tally, it throws HTML file contains response ‘Tally Server is Running’ with licence detail in place of XML response. Please help me? Getting correct response of XML when posted on education mode of tally. But when I post it over licence version getting this response 'Tally Server is running' with licence detail.

Comment: is there any setting in tally for gateway port no to allow external interface for XML interactions.gateway port number other than 9000.

Comment: I thought the port defaults to `9002`. Did you try that?

Comment: Jumped the gun on that one. Looks like `9000` is [the default](https://help.tallysolutions.com/tallyweb/modules/pss/crm/kb/search/CKBTallyHelpSearchWIC.php?strEventID=9&productID=10&docLink=td9rel54/td9/tally_developer_tools/tally_connector.htm&docTitle=Tally%20connector&search_type=1&strSearchString=9000&strSCIframeName=&strInvokedFromSupportCentreFlag=)

Answer (score 0):

Please check value of system variable named as SVExportFormat, this should have value as 'XML'

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you have not included the xml request while hitting the server and port. You need to add the xml request as a data parameter. For example, if you're using curl, it would be:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:9000 --data "[insert XML here]"
```